# SELECT into Array

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, executereader

I use `ExecuteReader()`.
It returns only the last result. I wanted to display the result like an array in `tbid_1.Text`, `tbid_1.Text`, `tbid_1.Text` etc.

```
    public void Select(FrmVIRGO frm)
                {

                string query = "SELECT* FROM tb_patient_information ";
                if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                { //Create Command
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                    //Create a data reader and Execute the command


          MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {

// I think use like this
                       frm.tbid_1.Text = dataReader["id_patient"][1].ToString(); //... id_patient1
                       frm.tbid_2.Text = dataReader["id_patient"][2].ToString(); //... id_patient2
                       frm.tbid_3.Text = dataReader["id_patient"][3].ToString(); //... id_patient3


                        }

                        //close Data Reader
                    dataReader.Close();

                    //close Connection
                    this.CloseConnection();
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be expecting that once you've called `dataReader.Read()`, you can access all of the records by an index.

Your data reader is an instance of `IDataReader`, the interface that most .NET data access libraries use to represent the concept of "reading the results of a query". `IDataReader` only gives you access to one record at a time. Each time you call `dataReader.Read()`, the `IDataReader` advances to the next record. When it returns `false`, it means that you have reached the end of the result set.

For example, you could transform your code above to something like this:

```
        dataReader.Read();  // dataReader is at 1st record
        frm.tbid_1.Text = dataReader["id_patient"].ToString();

        dataReader.Read();  // dataReader is at 2nd record
        frm.tbid_2.Text = dataReader["id_patient"].ToString();

        dataReader.Read();  // dataReader is at 3rd record
        frm.tbid_3.Text = dataReader["id_patient"].ToString();
```

Note that this is **not** the way you should do it, I'm just using it to illustrate the way a `DataReader` works.

If you are expecting exactly 3 records to be returned, you could use something similar to the code above. I would modify it to verify that `dataReader.Read()` returns `true` before you read data from each record, however, and handle a case where it doesn't in a meaningful way (e.g., throw an exception that explains the error, log the error, etc.).

Generally though, if I am working with raw ADO.Net (as opposed to using an [OR/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)) I prefer to convert each record in the `IDataReader` to a dictionary beforehand, and work with those.

For example, you could write the following extension method for `DataReader`:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static IList<IDictionary<string, object>> ListRecordsAsDictionaries(this IDataReader reader)
    {
        var list = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var record = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var key = reader.GetName(i);
                var value = reader[i];
                record.Add(key, value);
            }

            list.Add(record);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

This method iterates over the `IDataReader`, and sticks the values from each row into a `Dictionary<string, object>`. I have found this pattern to generally be fairly useful when dealing with raw ADO stuff.

This approach has a couple of caveats:

- You don't get access to the records (the Dictionary instances) until *all* of the data has been received from the server. If you are handling records individually as the `DataReader` makes them available, you may actually be able to start processing the data while some of it is still in-transit. (Note: This could be fixed by making this method return `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` instead of `IList<IDictionary<string, object>>`, and using `yield return` to yield each record as it becomes available.)
- If you are iterating over a large data set, you may not want to instantiate that many dictionaries. It may be better to just handle each record individually instead.
- You lose access to some of the information that `DataReader` can provide about the record(s) (e.g., you can't use `DataReader.GetDataTypeName` as you are iterating over the records).